# SELECT rows with MAX id minus 1 with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with id, city_id, and stock which looks like this.

| id | city_id | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 |
| 3 | 3 | 11000 |
| 4 | 2 | 600 |
| 5 | 3 | 12000 |
| 6 | 1 | 2000 |
| 9 | 3 | 13000 |
| 10 | 1 | 3000 |
| 11 | 1 | 4000 |
| 12 | 2 | 700 |

To select the latest stock values for each city_id I used the following query, which works fine.

```
SELECT `stock` 
FROM `stock_table` 
WHERE id in ( SELECT MAX(id) 
              FROM `stock_table` 
              GROUP BY city_id 
             );
```

It returns

| stock |
| --- |
| 13000 |
| 4000 |
| 700 |

Now I want to select 2nd latest stock entry for each city_id. So the output should be like the following table.

| stock |
| --- |
| 12000 |
| 3000 |
| 600 |

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8 you can use the `row_number()` window function to assign a number to each row ordered by the `id` per partition of `city_id`. Then just filter on that being `2` (in your example; you can use any number).

```
SELECT x.stock 
       FROM (SELECT s.stock,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s.city_id
                                       ORDER BY s.id DESC) rn
                    FROM stock_table s) x
       WHERE x.rn = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

u can use group by with row number and get rownumber 2
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY    city_id ORDER By id) as ROW